# Keras anomaly in its training time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I am using Keras in multi-gpu, with Tensorflow backend on 2 gpus. I am using a generator (keras.utils.Sequence) to load my data in batch mode (BS = 64). Therefore I am using the `fit_generator` class, providing it with my train and validation data and steps.
I noticed a strange behaviour starting from the 2nd epoch on. Basically, the first 3 steps of each epoch are completed in just 8/9 seconds each, then the network starts taking longer and longer (as it should do). Logs are the following:

```
Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.46875, saving model to data/subs_best_model.h5
Epoch 2/32
 1/29 [>.............................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 1.0664 - acc: 0.5000
 2/29 [=>............................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 1.1384 - acc: 0.4531
 3/29 [==>...........................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 1.0915 - acc: 0.5052
 4/29 [===>..........................] - ETA: 42:03 - loss: 1.1064 - acc: 0.5117
 5/29 [====>.........................] - ETA: 56:02 - loss: 1.1173 - acc: 0.4969
 6/29 [=====>........................] - ETA: 1:03:13 - loss: 1.0964 - acc: 0.4974
 7/29 [======>.......................] - ETA: 1:06:45 - loss: 1.0740 - acc: 0.5067
 8/29 [=======>......................] - ETA: 1:08:35 - loss: 1.0592 - acc: 0.5195
 9/29 [========>.....................] - ETA: 1:08:53 - loss: 1.0580 - acc: 0.5191
```

Do you know what could cause this anomaly/strange behaviour?

EDIT:

My `DataGenerator` is inspired by [this implementation](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

The code I use for the fit_generator is as follows:

```
params = {'batch_size':  TrainConfig.BATCH_SIZE,
              'dim' : ( TrainConfig.BATCH_SIZE, 1, TrainConfig.SAMPLES),
              'labels_dim': ( TrainConfig.BATCH_SIZE,),
              'n_classes' : TrainConfig.OUTPUT_DIM}

training_generator = DataGenerator(train_set, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(val_set, **params)

training_steps_per_epoch = int(1.*len(train_set) / batch_size)
validation_steps_per_epoch = int(1.*len(val_set) / batch_size)

history = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                              verbose=1,
                              use_multiprocessing=False,
                              workers=1,
                              steps_per_epoch=training_steps_per_epoch,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps =validation_steps_per_epoch,
                              callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: check your generator. it might we generating batches of different sizes after each call.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (at least your `fit_generator` )

Comment: Thanks, I just edited above.

Comment: You should include the code of the generator.